# PHP Exec function doesnot run imagemagick sheel command, but running same script properly from shell.

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am running following command through EXEC PHP function. I am creating JPG from PDF file from ImageMagick Library.

## Command:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -density 500 '/home/pop/www/pdf/pdfSample.pdf' -resize 18% '/home/pop/www/images/pdfSample.jpg'
```

I am getting following Responses from EXEC PHP function.

## Output Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CRIT: rangecheck in .setuserparams
    [1] => Operand stack:
    [2] =>     --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--
)
```

Exec Response: 1

Note: I have assigned 777 rights to PDF and IMAGES folder, but still getting same issue. I am running above command properly from shell.

Should I assign root owner group to PDF and IMAGES folder?

Please help me for this problem.

Thanks,
Raheel

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes poking at Google, the top search results suggests that `"CRIT: rangecheck in .setuserparams"` is an error in ImageMagick's `convert` program frequently caused by missing or ancient versions of Ghostscript and/or Freetype.

You'll want to get those installed and/or brought up to date.